# How do I print out the pair values in my array

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I fix `<zip object at 0x03B1C3C8>` in my program

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, grade, hours):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.grade = grade
        self.hours = hours

    def getName(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def getSurname(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.surname)

    def getGrade(self):
        return zip(self.grade, self.hours)

    def getHours(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.hours)

    def getQPoints(self):
        pass

stud1 = Student("John","Brown",["A","B","A"],["15.0","25.0","20.0"])
stud2 = Student("Mary","Watson","B","20")

print (stud1.getGrade())
print (stud1.getHours())
```

Comment: `return list(zip(self.grade, self.hours))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `list()` like below:

```
def getGrade(self):
    return list(zip(self.grade, self.hours))
```

**Note:** You do not need to apply `list()` if all you need is to loop over the returned `zip` object.

```
>>> for i, j in stud1.getGrade():
...     print(i, j)
...
('A', '15.0')
('B', '25.0')
('A', '20.0')
```

Comment: Thanks list() helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you totally forget zip :

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, grade, hours):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.grade = grade
        self.hours = hours

    def getName(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def getSurname(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.surname)

    def getGrade(self):
        return (self.grade, self.hours)

    def getHours(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.hours)

    def getQPoints(self):
        pass

stud1 = Student("John","Brown",["A","B","A"],["15.0","25.0","20.0"])
stud2 = Student("Mary","Watson","B","20")

print (stud1.getGrade())
print (stud1.getHours())
```

`return (self.grade, self.hours)` will create a tuple that you can then print

Answer (score 0):

From the python documentation, when you use `zip` it returns an iterator of tuples (that python defines with these '`()`').

It will probably be simplest to just iterate over your grades tuple like so:

```
for grade in stud1.getGrades():
    print("Grade: " + grade[0] + " Hours studied: " + grade[1])
```

This will give you:

```
Grade: A Hours studied: 15.0
Grade: B Hours studied: 25.0
Grade: A Hours studied: 20.0
```

But I would rather have `Student.getGrade` return the list of grades only. Then have another function `getReport` that prints the hours as well as the grades.

Comment: A good solution but my assignment says I have to do it with `print (stud1.getGrade())`